# finding $g(x)$ when it hasn't been given in the equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I  just recently took a test that shows $f(x)=9^x$ . and it says find the inverse function of $f(x)\; \& \;g(x)$ but it doesn't show $g(x)$,  So how do I solve for that?

Comment: Clearly there's no way to usefully write down the inverse of an unknown function, but I expect you have left off information.

Comment: Are you sure it didn't say that $g(x)$ was the inverse function of $f(x)$?  Then asking you to find $g(x)$ would make sense.

Comment: it just gives  f(x) but not g(x) and  to find the inverse function  of both of them but it  doesnt give g(x)

Comment: Clearly it's a mistake in the test.  This is something you should point out to your instructor.

Comment: I don't think it is a mistake. I think you are supposed to write it in terms of $g^{-1}(x)$. Also, what do you mean by $f(x)$&$g(x)$? Do you mean $f(g(x))$?

Comment: The inverse function of $f(x) = 9^x$ is $g(x) = \log_9(x)$. That's probably not the answer to the question on the exam. For that we need to see exactly what the whole question said, word for word, not just this recollection.